# Navigation Properties on Join Tables in Entity Framework

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework-4

So I have a table in my SQL database:

```
CompanyRelationships
--------------------
ID
CompanyID
RelatedCompanyID
PermissionGroupID
```

Which defines when a company allows access to it's records to another company.  The "CompanyID" is the company that is granting access, the "RelatedCompanyID" is the company that is getting the access.

Yes, two records could exist for the same two companies (each granting access to the other)

The problem is when I generate the entity model from the db (In Visual Studio 2010), the navigation properties I get are not exactly helpful as to which is which.  I get:

```
Company
Company1
UserGroup
```

UserGroup is of course obvious, but I would like to know which company reference is which, as that is kind of important.  I'm sure I could test it and find out, but then I would have to retest to be sure every time I regenerated from the database.  Is there a way to force the naming of the navigation property to be that of the FK field and not the entity it is linked to?

Comment: I made a basic .net console app for this https://github.com/timabell/ef-edmx-nav-namer

Comment: @TimAbell that's awesome, you should probably add it as an answer to this question so it is more visible to anyone else who reads this.  I think most people pass right over the comments.

Comment: Okay, if you think it's worthy :-) it's very rough and ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Could always Click on the Navigational Property on the Entity in the Model Browser, and look up the Properties Window. The Window Shows the Association Name (created when adding Table relationships in database). Once you identify the Relation, you could always rename the Navigational Property Name to a name of your choice.

Example, Clicking "Company1" Navigational property in the Entity Diagram would show you a relationship name as "Company_Id_to_Related_Company_Id" (or whatever the name is). Once you know what it means, you can rename the Navigational Property to a meaningful name such as "MasterCompany".

Comment: Ha, thats great, I kept looking in the properties window for something but didn't notice the Association name changed (it gets cut off at the end, the part that is different)

Answer (score 1):

Grab this command-line app https://github.com/timabell/ef-edmx-nav-namer, compile it in visual studio, and run it against your edmx file (take a backup first!) like this:

```
EfEdmxNavNamer.exe -i path\to\your\Model.edmx
```

For the following key name: `FK_Parent_Child` it will set the navigation properties at each end as follows:

- on the parent entity: "Child"
- on the child entity: "Parent"

This only really covers the most basic case, but it's something. Pull requests welcome if you want to improve on it. It's Apache 2.0 licensed.