# Problem with Navigation Property naming convention in EDMX

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

My Foreign Key Name in SQL is

FK_Employee_Departmemt_Source
FK_Employee_Departmemt_Status

but when i add Employee and Department table in EDMX, Entity Framework automatically change their names to

Department 
Department1

I want it to be remain the same, Kindly help.

Thanks

Comment: I made a basic .net console app for this https://github.com/timabell/ef-edmx-nav-namer

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database

Answer (score 1):

You want it to remain `FK_Employee_Departmemt_Status`? You should really read something about naming conventions in .NET. Never mind as I know you cannot change this behavior and you must modify names manually after updating from database. Moreover in this case you have a big change you will have to do it after each update of the entity containing that FK.

Comment: Actually renaming a Navigation property persists across updates.  I have done it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6203308/navigation-properties-on-join-tables-in-entity-framework

Comment: @Neil: It persists across "some" updates but not across all. I saw that in my own project and many other developers report the same issue. Sometime designer decides to rename silently property back to `XXX1`