# Renaming navigation properties

Tags: entity-framework-5, ef-database-first, navigation-properties

Sometimes entity framework generates awful navigation property names. Using the database first approach, what is the best way to fix that?

I am able to edit the t4 templates to my liking, but how would I bind these modified names to actual relations? Should I just write a script to modify the edmx file? Obviously, doing it by hand is is hardly an option.

Comment: There is no edmx in EF5. Are you talking about EF4?

Comment: @sza, that's odd, it claims to be Version 5 in Reference Properties. What I actually did was an "ADO.NET Entity Data Model".

Comment: I think this thread has a more detailed explanation of what to alter in the EF 5.x T4 templates to achieve this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database

Comment: I m using EF version 6, do they have anything to solve this issue? I am also renaming the navigation properties every time I recreate/reload the EDMX file in DB First project. Can u plz share the script that you are using to rename the properties? Thanks

Comment: I made a basic .net console app for this https://github.com/timabell/ef-edmx-nav-namer

Comment: very similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583352/problem-with-navigation-property-naming-convention-in-edmx

Comment: try using this solution [Define Rules to name Navigational Property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937193/improve-navigation-property-names-when-reverse-engineering-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can. In most of cases you just need to rename that NavPr from the EF model designer and save the model. Then EF renames that NavPr in your `DbContext.tt` entity classes and it cause no problem.

If you got problems with the ralation name, right-click at the renamed NavPr and select properties. Then change the `Association` property of it to the actual relation in your database.

If you can't see the relative relation name there, delete that entity and all other entities which has a relation to it, right-click on model designer and choose `Update model from database`. Then, simply rename that ugly NavPr and save the model.

Comment: I don't want to do it in the model designer. Often there are too many tables for that. Also, should there ever be a need to generate a new model, all the changes would be lost. What I'd like is a way to tell EF what naming conventions to use.

Comment: You just can remove the naming convention of EF by overriding `OnModelCreating` in DbContext, and by doing so, you must tell all things about naming properties, foreign keys, etc. to EF...! Which way is simpler?!

Comment: `OnModelCreating` is only for Code First, isn't it? I need a solution using Database First.

Comment: So you doesn't have a choice at all. Besides, it is possible to start with Db first, and change the way to Code first... Maybe you also are going this way...

Comment: Well, at the moment I've already written a Perl script to fix my .edmx, so I'm fine. I was hoping to find a more elegant solution though...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė you should have shared what you have found!